# Unable to install NuGet pck - Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure is not in my GAC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget, .net-assembly, gac

The error:
*Failed to add reference. The package 'SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi.WebHost.QuickStart' tried to add a framework reference to 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure' which was not found in the GAC. This is possibly a bug in the package. Please contact the package owners for assistance.
Cannot find assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure'.*

First of all. Why the error when I have the dll and reference to it in my project?
**Second. How do I fix this?**

Obviously I've tried to add the assembly to my GAC with various guides from Mircosoft. None of them makes sense imo.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-install-an-assembly-into-the-gac
This results in "Failure adding assembly to the cache:   The system cannot find the file specified." I guess that's because it's not a strongly typed name with a key pair or what ever. So I looked into this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-sign-an-assembly-with-a-strong-name
which makes absolutely no sense. It says:
"In the Choose a strong name key file box, choose , and then navigate to the key file. To create a new key file, choose  and enter its name in the Create Strong Name Key dialog box."

What key file? Create a new and just come up with a random name? Wtf? How is that related to a specific assembly?

Comment: I checked the nuspec file of SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi.Webhost.Quickstart and it added a reference to Microsoft.Web.Infrastructre as FrameworkAssembly `<frameworkAssemblies>
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.0" />
    </frameworkAssemblies>`

Comment: But as far as I am aware of `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` is a nuget package and is not part of the .net framework.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#framework-assembly-references

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer Aha I see. Maybe the Infrastructure assembly has been removed from the .net framework at some point. I'll try and contact the package owner.

Comment: @Kasper Skov , As far as I know, it was not installed in .NET Framework, other members also reported this issue before: https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/issues/1393 or https://forums.asp.net/t/2079021.aspx?elimitate+the+need+for+Microsoft+Web+Infrastructure+. Of course, if you get any latest information from the package owner, feel free to share the latest information.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Good, I was starting to be afraid I was the only one with the problem. I've added an answer with info from the package owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Schadensbegrenzer and @LeoLiu-MSFT pointed out, the Infrastrcuture assembly is not part of the .NET framework (anymore).

The issue has been reported as a bug on SimpleInjectors repo:
https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/509

The package owners solution:

"I'll add this issue to the v4.1 backlog, and will fix the NuGet package (and that of SimpleInjector.Integation.MVC3 as well) with v4.1.

In the meantime, you can manually add the Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure NuGet package to your Web API project or don't add the SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi.WebHost.QuickStart NuGet package to your project, but just the SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi NuGet package and add the required code manually. The WebHost.QuickStart package is in fact nothing more than a reference to the integration package while injected some code into your application anyway.

The Web API integration page in the documentation describes how to set up a Web API project using Simple Injector."

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue with error "`Unable to uninstall 'Ninject.3.2.2' because 'Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel.3.2.0, Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.3.2.0, Ninject.Web.3.2.0, Ninject.Web.Common.3.2.0' depend on it.`". 
It was caused by multiple projects in the solution having a dependency on those DLLs and so package manager was not able to uninstall it.

The command with "uninstall package-name -RemoveDependency" too doesn't work here.

I removed the dependency one by one to fix it.